# Display sum of 2 mysql colums in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do this simple sum of two boolean columns in a mysql database. And make a results pane with different calculations on these 2 values.
This is how the db looks like [db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lII81.png)

I'm trying to come up with a mysql statement that returns the sum of 'liked' and the sum of 'disliked'

Then I need to have this value in 2 formats:

- as an integer (just the count)
- as a percentage

This is how my php code looks like:

```
  if(isset($_GET['results'])){
  $get_votes = 'SELECT liked SUM(1), disliked SUM(1) AS total FROM live';
  $run_votes = mysqli_query($con, $get_votes);
  $row_votes = mysqli_fetch_array($run_votes);

  $disliked = $row_votes['disliked']
  $liked = $row_votes['liked'];

  $count = $disliked+$liked;

  $per_disliked = round($disliked*100/$count) . "%";
  $per_liked = round($liked*100/$count) . "%";

  $per_dislikedclean = round($disliked*100/$count);
  $per_likedclean = round($liked*100/$count);
```

I'm getting a 'division by zero' error. This is probably because mysqli_fetch_array expects a mysqli_result. Can anyone shed a light on this topic ?

Comment: What happens when you execute the query manually? (using the mysql command line or phpmyadmin)

Comment: Try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead.

Comment: Hi Jocelyn I tried executing the query directly on the db. but its giving me a SQL syntax error. 

It works with this syntax:

SELECT SUM(liked), SUM(disliked) FROM live

Comment: I've replaced the statement in $get_votes
But now its giving me an unexpected "$liked" variable on line 7 of my code snippet i posted above.

This is telling me that $row_votes is not initiated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below SQL to get your desired result

```
SELECT SUM(liked) As liked, SUM(disliked) AS disliked, ( SUM(liked)*100 )/count(*) AS like_perc, ( SUM(disliked)*100)/count(*) AS dislike_perc FROM live
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice statement Jignesh. This gives me 4 values. 
How can I detach the int value and the per value ?